# Insert, get id and insert at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two PHP functions that have to be executed at the same time. I need to use two different functions because, for example, I create a course in my app and at the same time I add multiple homework for my students. Here's my simplified code:

```
function createCourse($courseName) {
    global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix; 
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO courses (name) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $courseName);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    return $result;
}

function addHomeworkToCourse($homeworkDescription) {
    global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;
    $course = "13"; // Here comes the problem: how do I get the ID inserted in the previous function
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO homework (course, description) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $course, $homeworkDescription);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    return $result;
}
```

And the form to create a course and add some homework to it in the same page:

```
createCourse("Maths");
addHomeworkToCourse("Resolve this equation"); // Add some homework to "Maths"
```

Thanks for your time! (Please note that I'm not an expert PHP, MySQL and English)

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: Could you modify the first function to return the id of the last row inserted if successful. You can then pass this value to the 2nd function. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php. You will have to modify the 2nd function to add another argument which will be the id of the course for which you are adding the homework description.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I tried mysqli_insert_id but it returned nothing (I don't know if I'm doing something wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$id = createCourse("Maths");
addHomeworkToCourse($id, "Resolve this equation");
```

have the createCourse return the id of the course with last inserted id.

php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

This would also make the add HomeworkToCourse method/function more robust and able to be used in a variety of situations

Answer (score 0):

With `mysql` you can use the php function `mysqli_insert_id` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)) to get the last inserted ID of the course, then you can add the homework to it.

Comment: I stealth edited my typo just before you commented. The link was always pointed to the mysqli version in the docs

Comment: ...and I've stealthily deleted the comment.